# How to make a textarea appear just as much as the text?

Tags: html, css, resize, size, textarea

As the title says, when I make a textarea with text, I want the area to only be as big as the text, without me having to specify how many rows and cols. Is that even possible? Worst-case scenario I specify how many cols, but at least let the rows be just as much as the text!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: There's quite a lot about this already on SO - have a look around for ideas, try some code and if still stuck show us what you have tried with a description of what isn't working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.